# Drupal 7: fetchField(0) giving me half of the records!

Tags: database

I am trying to get all the records from one table. I get from the count 18 record, but the actual given lines are 9.

```
$name = 'admin';
$result = db_query("SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE name <> :name", array(':name' => $name));
$rownum = $result->rowCount();
print "This is the total number: ";
print $rownum;
print "<BR>";
foreach ($result as $record) {
  $value = $result->fetchField(0);
  print $value;
print '<br>';
}
```

Results:

> This is the total number: 18
>   user1
>   user2
>   user3
>   user4
>   user5
>   user6
>   user7
>   user8
>   user9

Do you think is my loop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the loop iterates through `result`, but additionally you do that kind of again in your line `$value = $result->fetchField(0);`.

This should be changed to `$value = $record->name;`.